# How can I call a method on an instance within the instance class?

Tags: java, methods, instance-variables

```
    public class Agent {
        private Space _location;
        private String _name;
        public void setLocation(Space space){
            _location = space;
        }
        public void usePortal(){
            if(_location.getPortal() != null){
            Portal.transport(Agent.this);
            }
        }
    }
```

java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method transport(Agent) from the type Portal

Above is the error it gives me. I have a public class Space with a member variable of type Portal and a getPortal() getter. which looks like:

```
    public class Space {
        private String _name;
        private String _description;
        private Portal _portal;
        public Portal getPortal(){
            return _portal;
        }
    }
```

In my public Portal class, I have a transport method with an Agent parameter:

```
    public class Portal {
        private String _name;
        private String _direction;
        private Space _destination;
        public Space getDestination(){
            return _destination;
        }
        public void transport(Agent str){
            str.setLocation(getDestination());
        }
    }
```

My main problem is having the usePortal() method to work, the Space and Portal classes are fully functional. I don't know how I would call the method on an instance of Agent within the Agent class.

Comment: I don't understand your title. You're calling the instance method `transport` from the instance class `Agent`. Just make an instance of `Portal` and then call `portalInstance.transport(this);`?

Comment: Learn `static & this keyword` first !!

Answer (score 1):

> java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: Cannot make a static
>   reference to the non-static method transport(Agent) from the type
>   Portal

This is because transport method is an `instance` method and not `static`.

Either create an instance of `Portal` and then use that or make the `transport` method static

```
Portal portal = new Portal();
portal.transport(this);
```

or

```
public static void transport (Agent str)
```

> I don't know how I would call the method on an instance of Agent
>   within the Agent class.

Instead of `Agent.this` use just `this`

Comment: Nice assumption skipping static method usage !!

Comment: @WundwinBorn added static method usage issue as well

Comment: Good explanation and +1 back !! Anyway should post code along with !

Answer (score 1):

You can't call other class methods without initializing an object reference. Unless it is declared static.

For example:

```
Portal portal = new Portal();
portal.transport(this);
```

Note that `this` is a reference to the current object, in this case, Agent.

Do some more research online to see how java objects work and also research static and non-static contexts. Tons of examples!

Comment: You should explain `this` keyword too !!

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
public void usePortal(){
    if(_location.getPortal() != null){
    _location.getPortal().transport(this);
    }
}
```